# Use WCF to trace data

Tags: wcf, bug-tracking

We've found a bug in a program that we bought from another company, which doesn't exist any more. The bug is somehow major, we have to figure out at which module/step the error occurs. We know the tracing data which are simply what the end user types into the program. Is it possible to using WCF to realize such debugging? If it is possible, where could man find some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable service tracing on both the service and client ends:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

**UPDATE**

It's not that hard. You can find simpler examples than that easily. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreal/archive/2009/03/21/wcf-end-to-end-tracing.aspx

Then you can read the logfiles generated by using SvcTraceViewer.exe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! It seems a huge work to read thru it. Is any program, sayer logger, available?